# Custom Audience - 300 user limit?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

I keep adding new members to my custom audience, but the Facebook ad manager says that the Audience is only 300 members. I've uploaded about twice that.

Also, I have a re-targeting audience based on a pixel on my website and it's also topped out at 300 members.

Either there is a limit to the number of audience members, or the ad manager doesn't tell you the total members in your custom audience.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

From [Facebook for developers FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-website/faq/v2.8):

> Q: How many audiences can I create?
>
> A: At this time, there is a maximum of **10000** Custom Audiences from your Website that can be created in a single account.

See the [Hailey's answers](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10207536802639216) from Facebook Help Team on this topic:

> There's no maximum to the number of people you can add to your audience, but keep in mind you can only add 10,000 people at a time.

Comment: Yes, but my account says I have 300 members. Exactly 300. I've uploaded over 600... something's screwey.